# execute sql which is placed in an xml file using Java code

Tags: java, sql, xml

how to execute sql which is placed in an xml file using Java code?

Answer (score 1):

- Load the SQL Statement as a String out of the XML into a Java Variable (Using [SAX](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html) or [DOM](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html), for example)
- Execute the [SQL Statement](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

Comment: how to take the sql out to xml...? i want to execute it from the XML....could you post the code?

Comment: Can you post (an example/part of) the XML?

Comment: <sqlQuery>select * from table<sqlQuery>